# run immediately function is disabled in sql server 2012 import wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to import Excel files into a database without having to save it as an SSIS package but the "run immediately option is grayed out.  How can I enable the "run immediately".

Comment: did you fullfill all pre-requets?

Comment: I have been using the wizard on SQL from 2000 onwards but this is my first time with 2012 and I did all I normally do including the mapping.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and it seems to be to do with trying to convert fields at the same time as doing the import. I was trying to convert a datetime to a nvarchar. To solve this I changed the data in that field in Excel to text, and next time I tried to import the Run Immediately option was available again.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be able to check run immediately you have to fix a few lines in excel if it matches the required data type.

**First**, you have to compare data types between source and destination
[image]

**Second**, change the format of the data in the column in Excel
[image]